# How can get folder name when upload folder in Blazor component?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I upload a folder , my code in file.razor:

I can get list file in folder:

```
  @page "/uploadfolder"
  
  <InputFile OnChange="@LoadFiles" webkitdirectory directory />
  @code {  
    private List<IBrowserFile> loadedFiles = new();
   
    private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {       
        loadedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles().ToList();
        foreach (var file in loadedFiles)
        {
            
        }

        
    }
}
```

How can get Name of Folder selected and Name of subfolder ?

Comment: Getting a directory handle in a browser is not well supported.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle

Comment: Server cannot read from the client’s file system. Because extra information about client’s file system could potentially be exploited in some way.

Comment: I only want get Name of Folder, not get path of file.

Comment: @DT Why don't you follow up when you ask a question? I had this question. I saw that an answer was posted here, but you did not react to the answer so that I know whether it is correct or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need some JavaScript because unfortunately BLAZOR does not provide  this information :

first add id to input file:

```
<InputFile  id="myFileUpload" OnChange="@LoadFiles" webkitdirectory directory />
```

Then add this code to the end of ‍`_Host.cshtml` file In order to provide its information to the blazor component when a file is selected:

```
<script>

window.attachFileUploadHandler = () => {
    document.getElementById("myFileUpload").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
       
        var files = [];

        Array.from(e.target.files).forEach(file => {
            files.push({ Name: file.name, Path: file.webkitRelativePath});
        });

       //replcae BlazorApp1 with your application assembly name
        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorApp1', 'GetSelectedFileDetails',files);
    });
};
 </script>
```

Then create a class to get the file information from JavaScript:

```
public class FileForUploadDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

then add Invokable method from javascript to your component  :

```
private static List<FileForUploadDetails> _selectedFileFromJs = new();

[JSInvokable]
public static Task GetSelectedFileDetails(List<FileForUploadDetails> files)
{
    _selectedFileFromJs = files;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Attach Java script Event Listener After Component Rendered:

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("attachFileUploadHandler");
}
```

Then the loadfile method changes as follows :

```
private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    loadedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles(50).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < loadedFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        //here you can access folder path and split by / and get all folder and sub folders
        var filePath = _selectedFileFromJs[i].Path;

        var file = loadedFiles[i];
    }
}
```

So the entire code of the component is as follows

```
@page "/uploadfolder"

@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime

<InputFile  id="myFileUpload" OnChange="@LoadFiles" webkitdirectory directory />

@code {

private static List<FileForUploadDetails> _selectedFileFromJs= new();

private List<IBrowserFile> loadedFiles = new();

protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("attachFileUploadHandler");
}

private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    loadedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles(50).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < loadedFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        var filePath = _selectedFileFromJs[i].Path;

        var file = loadedFiles[i];
    }
}

[JSInvokable]
public static Task GetSelectedFileDetails(List<FileForUploadDetails> files)
{
    _selectedFileFromJs= files;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}


 public class FileForUploadDetails
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
 } 
}
```